# {EPILEPSY WARNING} Windows 10 Infinite Throbber and Screen Reset on Grey Screen

Tags: boot, windows-10, bsod

Windows 10 has chosen to have infini-seizures on me at the grey startup screen:

[image: Windows 10 Grey Screen Seizure]

All goofiness aside, this occurred on what should be a normal restart of the system.  I assume some updates may have been applied, but unfortunately I'm not seeing any way to roll the system back to a previous point or such.

Any ideas on how to get into Safe Mode or to stop this from occurring?  Since it does reset to the black screen each time, I have to suspect there is some crash occurring and Windows is simply trying to restart the window server or something to that effect in quick succession.

Comment: F8F8F8F8F8F8F8F8F8F8F8F8? It's been a long time since I tried to enter Safe Mode.

Comment: LOL, yeah, I wish `F8` still worked! Been a while since we've been screwed out of that one...